# TP-Link WN321G USB wlan  in VirtualBox Ubuntu guest

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, wifi

I am trying wifi usb stick tp-link wn321g @ ubuntu 11.04 (in virtualbox), so far I was able to scan the air, connect to a wpa2 network and do some basic information gathering using airodump-ng

Now when it comes to packet injection, seems that firmware is not capable.
to be more specific, I am locking the wlan0 to a specific channel for `aireplay-ng` and it ignores me completely, setting channel to -1

```
root@delta:~# iwconfig wlan0 channel 1
root@delta:~# airmon-ng start wlan0 1
Interface       Chipset         Driver

wlan0           Unknown         rt2800usb - [phy0]
                                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
root@delta:~# iwconfig wlan0
wlan0 IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
      Tx-Power=20 dBm
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on
 airodump-ng -c1 mon0
 CH  1 ][ Elapsed: 8 s ][ 2011-07-27 17:22 ][ fixed channel mon0: -1

 BSSID              PWR RXQ  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID


 BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost  Packets  Probes

root@delta:~# aireplay-ng -0 1 -a 00:26:18:D8:CC:89 -c 00:1E:65:7B:81:34 mon0
17:43:56  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 00:26:18:D8:CC:89) on channel -1
17:44:02  mon0 is on channel -1, but the AP uses channel 1
root@delta:~#
```

I have tried different modules ( rt2800usb, rt2870sta ) rt2800usb works for airodump-ng and information gathering, rt2870sta works with `wpa_supplicant` for network connection - not the other way around for some reason.

Does anyone have an experience with this wifi card / chipset / firmware and successfully used aircrack suite for pen testing? below some specific data :

```
root@delta:~# uname -a
Linux delta 2.6.38-10-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 15:05:41 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

root@delta:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:2070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2070 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root@delta:~# lsmod |grep ^rt
rt2800usb              22184  0
rt2800lib              52239  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00usb              19915  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              47674  3 rt2800usb,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
```